Can I use single Blazor application as a module for different applications?
I have Blazor application. I want to use it with different databases. I could achieve it by hardcoding appName. This is program.cs
Dictionary<string, string> connStrs = new Dictionary<string, string>(); connStrs.Add("DB1", builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnection")); connStrs.Add("DB2", builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnection1")); DbContextFactory.SetConnectionString(connStrs); var dbContext = DbContextFactory.Create(appname);
I want appname set by query parameter to connect. I am trying _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext which shows null and not sure how to actually use it.

It sounds like a security risk. Be very sure you want to depend on the query string.

I don't have concrete code but you can wrap the DbContextFactory by something that uses the query parameters. Or look into keyed entries in the DI.
